# Why is my PHP while() inside while() not going up?

Tags: php

I'm using this simple while loops inside of a while loop and whats happening is the `$x` is working how i planned but the `$i` isnt.

```
$i = 0;
$x = 0;

while ($i <= 50) {
    while ($x <= 50) {
        echo $i . $x . "<BR/>";
        $x++;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

I'm getting the response;

```
00
01
0...
050
```

but then the script is stopping? `$i` isn't incrementing and running the while loop 50 more times so i would have

```
00
01
0...
050
10
11
1...
150
```

Comment: You don't reset `$x` to `0` on the next iteration of the outer loop. How to find such problems: 1. learn how to use debugger 2. try to evaluate your code manually on paper

Comment: Where is this 'debugger' i didn't have a bug the code worked as I wrote it just not as expected

Comment: "just not as expected" --- and that stands as a definition of a bug.

Comment: Can you tell me the debugging tool what also knows what I expect please?

Comment: Debugging tools know nothing - you use them to debug your code. It is you that must compare the actual and expected outcomes using a debugger. As of php - it would be `xdebug`

Comment: @ConorReidd what??? If the code "worked as I wrote it just not as expected" then why are you asking a question on SO? You obviously already know the problem if you know that it "worked as I wrote it just not as expected".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have to initialize `$x` to `0` at the beginning of the outer while loop. Your `$x` variable will never enter the inner while loop because `$x` is already greater than 50

```
$i = 0;

while ($i <= 50) {
    $x = 0;
    while ($x <= 50) {
        echo $i . $x . "<BR/>";
        $x++;
    }
    $i++;
}
```